# Проблема с запуском UI Automator viewer на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, appium, uiautomation

Я использую Ubuntu 18.04, хочу автоматизировать android эмулятор с помощью Appium. Для работы с селектором мне нужен UI Automator viewer из android-sdk. Я запускаю его следующим образом.

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/
```

затем

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
$ ./uiautomatorviewer
```

Но потом я получаю ошибку:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло поставить версию java-8-jdk основной в системе(до этого была java-11-openjdk)